# implicit Objective-C entrypoint -[AppiApp.InterractionUIApplication idleTimerExceeded]

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

i have following code i want to run this code in swift 4 . for checking app is idle 5 minutes  go to login screen but its show me error below.
i think this code is swift 3 . i am new in Ios please help me this thanks

> implicit Objective-C entrypoint -[AppiApp.InterractionUIApplication
>   idleTimerExceeded] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4

main.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

CommandLine.unsafeArgv.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc))
{    argv in
    _ = UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, argv, NSStringFromClass(InterractionUIApplication.self), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
}
```

logic for check idle

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension NSNotification.Name {
    public static let TimeOutUserInteraction: NSNotification.Name = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TimeOutUserInteraction")
}


class InterractionUIApplication: UIApplication {

    static let ApplicationDidTimoutNotification = "AppTimout"

    // The timeout in seconds for when to fire the idle timer.
    let timeoutInSeconds: TimeInterval = 15//15 * 60

    var idleTimer: Timer?

    // Listen for any touch. If the screen receives a touch, the timer is reset.
    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
        super.sendEvent(event)
        // print("3")
        if idleTimer != nil {
            self.resetIdleTimer()
        }

        if let touches = event.allTouches {
            for touch in touches {
                if touch.phase == UITouchPhase.began {
                    self.resetIdleTimer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Resent the timer because there was user interaction.
    func resetIdleTimer() {
        if let idleTimer = idleTimer {
            // print("1")
            idleTimer.invalidate()
        }

        idleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeoutInSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(self.idleTimerExceeded), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    // If the timer reaches the limit as defined in timeoutInSeconds, post this notification.
    func idleTimerExceeded() {
        print("Time Out")

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:Notification.Name.TimeOutUserInteraction, object: nil)

        //Go Main page after 15 second

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SliderViewController") as! SliderViewController //LoginActivity
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()// go activity


    }
}
```

Comment: Put `@objc` before `func idleTimerExceeded()`?

Comment: @objc func idleTimerExceeded() { }  like this ??